# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: \gexec

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a database in PostSql if it doesn't exist yet, the problem is that the IF NOT EXISTS method doesn't work on PostSQL.
The alternative gives me the following error, does anyone know what the problem is, unfortunately I couldn't find anything about it on the net

**Error:**

```
File "C:\Users\PC-66\PycharmProjects\bigdata\bigdata\database\create_postsql.py", line 68, in create_database_bigdata_postsql
cursor.execute("SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE mydb'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb')\gexec")
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »\«
LINE 1: ...XISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb')\gexec
```

**Code in Python:**

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

db = psycopg2.connect(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    user=user,
    password=password
)
db.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE mydb' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb')\gexec")
```

Answer (score 1):

`\gexec` is a psql command, not a part of the SQL syntax. It only works in psql, not when executing SQL by other means.